# How to connect to MongoDB replicaset on Kubernetes

Tags: mongodb, kubernetes, bitnami, replicaset

I have deployed [bitnami's Mongodb helm chart](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/master/bitnami/mongodb) in the replicaset mode on a K8s cluster, using this minimal config (for now):

```
  architecture: replicaset
  auth:
    enabled: false
```

Now I have two replicas (one primary and one secondary, allegedly) and an arbiter (no data, just voting rights). Additionally, I got two services: `appname-mongodb-headless`, `appname-mongodb-arbiter-headless`. However, the [MongoDB docs](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/) specify the connection string in case of replicaset installations as `mongodb://mongodb0.example.com:27017,mongodb1.example.com:27017,mongodb2.example.com:27017/?replicaSet=myRepl`.

I can use `mongodb://appname-mongodb-headless:27017` to connect to the db, but is it the "real experience" (i.e. highly available, etc)?

- Do I need to specify the replicaset name (as in the example) and how do I find out what it is?
- If the current services are enough, do I need to include the arbiter in the connection string?
- Or should I create separate services for each replica and build the recommended connection string?

  ```
  externalAccess:
    enabled: true
    autoDiscovery:
      enabled: true
  ```
- I will eventually enable authentication after sorting out this part of the connection. What is this `replicaSetKey` (*"Key used for authentication in the replicaset"*), and where do I use it?

I found [this similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/61490287/connection-to-mongodb-replicaset-on-kubernetes/61514163#61514163). It is for another chart, but it suggests me that some combination of the headless services should be enough. Nonetheless, it doesn't answer all aspects of my question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The headless service serves as an entrypoint for you to connect to MongoDB, without the need to specify a pod address. Kubernetes will balance the load and serve it to a specific pod.

If you wish to connect to MongoDB, using `externalAccess.enabled`, you should take a look at the Helm deployment notes that are shown when you deploy the chart. You can read them post-deployment by executing the `helm get notes MY-RELEASE` command.

For instance, in my case, it shows this, though depending on the deployment options it would show something else:

```
To connect to your database, create a MongoDB&reg; client container:

    kubectl run --namespace default mbmongo-mongodb-client --rm --tty -i --restart='Never' --env="MONGODB_ROOT_PASSWORD=$MONGODB_ROOT_PASSWORD" --image docker.io/bitnami/mongodb:4.4.8-debian-10-r24 --command -- bash

Then, run the following command:
    mongo admin --host "mbmongo-mongodb-0.mbmongo-mongodb-headless.default.svc.cluster.local:27017,mbmongo-mongodb-1.mbmongo-mongodb-headless.default.svc.cluster.local:27017,mbmongo-mongodb-2.mbmongo-mongodb-headless.default.svc.cluster.local:27017" --authenticationDatabase admin -u root -p $MONGODB_ROOT_PASSWORD

To connect to your database nodes from outside, you need to add both primary and secondary nodes hostnames/IPs to your Mongo client. To obtain them, follow the instructions below:

    MongoDB&reg; nodes domain: you can reach MongoDB&reg; nodes on any of the K8s nodes external IPs.

        kubectl get nodes -o wide

    MongoDB&reg; nodes port: You will have a different node port for each MongoDB&reg; node. You can get the list of configured node ports using the command below:

        echo "$(kubectl get svc --namespace default -l "app.kubernetes.io/name=mongodb,app.kubernetes.io/instance=mbmongo,app.kubernetes.io/component=mongodb,pod" -o jsonpath='{.items[*].spec.ports[0].nodePort}' | tr ' ' '\n')"
```

From the notes you can see this line:

> To connect to your database nodes from outside, you need to add both primary and secondary nodes hostnames/IPs to your Mongo client

That means that you do need to specify all primary/secondary node names, but not arbiters.

---

As for `replicaSetKey`, it refers to the contents of the MongoDB `keyFile` to use for internal cluster replication, so it can happen in a secure manner. You can read more about it [here](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/tutorial/enforce-keyfile-access-control-in-existing-replica-set/#enforce-keyfile-access-control-on-existing-replica-set).

If you continue finding issues, I suggest you create an issue in the [`bitnami/charts`](https://github.com/bitnami/charts/issues/) repository.

Comment: I read the chart's description but I always forget about the deployment notes. Thank you for bringing that up, it does actually explain it in details. It made me realize I missed the point of the service being headless, the `mongodb://appname-mongodb-headless:27017`  URL connects to the db through a proxy, I actually need to list the two pod service addresses so that my app knows about the replicas.

Answer (score 0):

Adding to Marcos' answer, there is another URI format called **DNS Seed List Connection Format** from 3.6+ which you can use with a single host name of  your headless service and still take advantage of the replicaset.

`mongodb+srv://server.example.com/`

It is described here: https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/connection-string/#dns-seed-list-connection-format